# Create a form with a for in Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I created a form in Symfony like this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($template)
    ->add('product1', 'text')
    ->add('product2', 'text')
    ->add('save', 'submit')
    ->getForm();
```

Now this is my twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
   {% for i in 1..2 %}
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="product">
            <div class="name">
               {{ form_label(form.product{{ i }} ) }}
               {{ form_errors(form.product{{ i }} ) }}
               {{ form_widget(form.product{{ i }} ) }}
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }
```

The main idea is iterate over the for and get a new `form.product<X>` each loop.
I can't make it works and I don't even know if it can be done in this way. Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you want to use collection type? It will be easier;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Collection type for this purpose. But if you want do it your way you should do it this way:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
   {% for i in 1..2 %}
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="product">
            <div class="name">
               {{ form_label( attribute(form, 'product' ~ i) ) }}
               {{ form_errors( attribute(form, 'product' ~ i) ) }}
               {{ form_widget( attribute(form, 'product' ~ i) ) }}
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }
```

Comment: I would have provided a Collection example also but this is a good answer

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it probably won't work. For information, concatenation symbol in Twig is "~".
In your case, if your entity is supposed to have 2 or more "products" you should use collections instead of creating manually each product.
In your entity you would have something like

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $products;
```

And on the product entity, you would have

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;
```

And then in your first entity __constructor or in your controller you iterate to create as many product as you want and you add them to the entity.

In your form, you would just have to add :

```
$builder->add('products', 'collection');
```

and you would be able to iterate on it in Twig.

Hopefully this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should start with a Entity with only a ManyToOne relation to the "product" entity. Lets say that we call this entity "ProductContainer".

Then you create an form for the ProductContainer with only one field with the type 'collection' which will make a list of products for you.

You can follow this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html